# How do I add this control to ASP.NET 4?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to add this control to my ASP.NET project in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web:
http://www.freetextbox.com/

I'm using WebForms.

The directions just say this:
"The most-used free ASP.NET WYSIWYG HTML editor featured in open source and commerical projects. Just drop FreeTextbox.dll in your /bin/ folder, change

```
<asp:Textbox /> to <FTB:FreeTextbox />,
```

and you're done. "

Okay. Well, I added FreeTextbox.dll to my project's bin folder. 
I changed

```
 <asp:Textbox /> to <FTB:FreeTextbox />
```

And I'm supposed to be done.

But the code is not recognizing 'FTB'. I also tried adding it as a reference, but I'm still getting the same problem.

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Comment: Try adding the control to your Visual Studio toolbar (you may have to browse for the reference) and once its in the toolbar just drag it onto the page

Comment: The code still doesn't recognize 'FTB..'

Comment: You also need to register the control in either your page or web.config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009138/asp-net-custom-control-unknown-server-tag or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706633/registering-custom-controls-fails

Answer (score 1):

I think the web site is lying. You also need this at the top of the page:

```
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="FTB" Namespace="FreeTextBoxControls" Assembly="FreeTextBox" %>
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's lying, but it probably expects devs familiar with ASP.NET WebForms to understand the additional step (first step, really) of registering the control - either on the page or in the Web.config.

Comment: @Tim - The web site is lying:  "Just drop FreeTextbox.dll in your /bin/ folder, change <asp:Textbox /> to <FTB:FreeTextbox />, and you're done. "  That is not true.