# ASP.NET Register WebControl to use in ASPX Page

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms, web-controls

I have created a WebControl **VideoStreaming** for video streaming using following link:

[Video Streaming with ASPNET SignalR and Html5](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/video-streaming-with-asp-net-signalr-and-html5)

**VideoStreaming.vb**

```
<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(VideoStreaming))> 

Namespace Lantern.Demo.Client.CustomControl

    Public Class VideoStreaming
        Inherits WebControl

    '.... All code here

    End Class

End Namespace
```

After writing all code, I declared/added/registered this control in my **Web.config** file as:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="VideoStreaming" tagPrefix="Web" namespace="Lantern.Demo.Client.CustomControl"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

But I am not able to add it in ASPX page as a regular control. This is what I am trying:

```
<web:VideoStreaming runat="server" ID="video" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="300px" Height="300px" 
            Interval="100" Source="True" ScalingMode="TargetSize" StreamingMode="Target" TargetClientID="received" OnStreamed="onStreamed" 
            Style="border: solid 1px black" />
```

This highlights the following Error:

```
Element 'VideoStreaming' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in Website, or the Web.config file is missing.
```

[image]

I have also tried registering the control using **<%Register%>** directory.

```
<%@ Register Namespace="Lantern.Demo.Client.CustomControl" TagPrefix="Web" Assembly="VideoStreaming"%>
```

But this is also not working. What I am missing or what I have to do?

I have seen following links:

1. [How to register User Control and Custom Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config)
2. [Registering Custom Controls Fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706633/registering-custom-controls-fails)

Please let me know if more information is required. Thanks

**EDIT:** Just to let you know that this is not an **.ascx** control. It is *WebControl* which has no UI.

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Did you add the assembly containing the WebControl to the web.config assembly section? If i'm not mistaken that's needed to 'set the reference' from your 'web project'.

Comment: Are you saying like this:
<assemblies>
        <add assembly="Lantern.Demo.Client.CustomControl" />
</assemblies>

If it is so, then I have also tried it and don't know how to get Cultural and Public Token information.

Comment: Yes, that is what i ment. OT: To get the public key token use the "SN.EXE" tool. SN -T {yourassembly}. To get the culture you can use powershell: [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("YourDllName.dll").GetName().CultureInfo.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more